# How does the cross section of bound state look like in scattering process?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, scattering-cross-section

I am studying the non-relativistic scattering theory. I know when the incident particle is in the bound state the scattering amplitude diverges. Then does it mean the cross section also diverge? If so, what does this divergence mean?

I think the cross section should be zero because the incident particle is in the bound state so no scattering should be detected by the detector.